# Automate data insert to SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I am looking for the best way to night batch data files into SQL Azure from a local system.

Comment: What options are you considering?  What are the considerations for accessing of your local data from Azure?

Comment: I just want to dump data to Azure nightly. Ideally, have a csv file that is processed on Azure SQL nightly, e.g. the file is dumped into a temporary table and a stored procedure processes it

Comment: I'm assuming you are going to insert large amount of data from local machine to SQL Azure. Then I prefer BCP. It inserts records in batch (1000 by default) with high performance as it doesn't check any constraints.